# page does not change from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, github-pages

I am working on a website using Jekyll through github-pages.  I am working on some simple javascripts to make a random number generator, but they aren't able to change values on the page.

The page has the following:

**/resume/index.html**

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="#d" maxlength="3" value="1" />
<div class="dice_text">d</div>
<input type="text" name="d#" maxlength="2" value="4" />
<button type="button" name="rollme" onclick="roll()">roll</button>
<div class="dice_text"> : </div>
<input type="text" id="dieresult" readonly />
</form>
```

**/resume/roll.js**

```
document.getElementById('dieresult').setAttribute('value', '3') ;

function roll() {
  alert("rolled!");
}
```

For some reason I don't understand, the roll() function will get called and give an alert when you press the button, so the site seems to be incorporating the javascript file, but it refuses to alter the page to display a number in the read only field.

My repo is online at [github](https://github.com/SplendidStrontium/splendidstrontium.github.io), and the problem site url is [here](http://nan.nyc/roll).

EDITED: corrected 'id' vs 'name' issue but page still won't change the value of 'dieresult'

Comment: Silly mistake, but changing the html to indicate an 'id' instead doesn't seem to fix the issue.  The issue is still present at http://nan.nyc/roll

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking the `name` attribute with the [`id` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

When you attempt to grab that element using `document.getElementById`, it will return `null`.

Making the id **dieresult** should fix this. I highly suggest getting cozy with your browser's inbuilt JavaScript console - you pick up on minor mistakes like this very quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input type="text" name="dieresult" readonly />` does not have an ID, which is what you are looking for in the line `document.getElementById('dieresult').setAttribute('value', '3') ;`

If you change the `<input type="text" name="dieresult" readonly />` to `<input type="text" id="dieresult" readonly />` and place this in the roll() function it should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

your input has a name but you query it by id, change it to this:

`<input type="text" name="dieresult" id="dieresult" readonly />`

Answer (score 0):

You have a 404 on jquery. Fix this by putting a jquery in your `roll` folder.

And, you can try to execute you code once everybody is onboard

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('dieresult').setAttribute('value', '3') ;
});
```

See http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#launching-code-on-document-ready